# Positive definite Hermitian matrices and non-leading principal minors

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, hermitian-matrices

I know that a Hermitian matrix is positive definite if and only if all of it's *leading* principal minors are positive. But now I had a discussion in which someone claimed that positive definiteness of a Hermitian matrix implies that *all* principal minors (i.e. not just the leading ones) are positive. Is this true? How can I prove it? I could not find a definite reference for this.

Comment: If $M$ is positive definite, so is $PHP'$, where $P$ is any permutation matrix.

Comment: @kimchilover That `H` is supposed to be an `M` right? I guess that is trivial to show, and then what I wrote follows because you could permute a matrix such that any principal minor becomes a leading principal minor? I don't completely see how you can accomplish that.

Comment: @kimchilover Ah nvm, yeah I get it now.

Comment: You are right, I mixed up $H$ and $M$.  I agree with your analysis in your comment.